# How to get additional data with terms aggregation in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping for a skills object:

```
    skills: {
      type: 'nested',
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: 'short',
        },
        name: 'text',
        keyword: 'keyword',
      },
    }
```

I need to find the top 5 most used skills among all the documents. For this, I made the following terms query:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "most_used_skill": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "skills"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "skill": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "skills.keyword",
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the result that I want like this:

```
"aggregations": {
    "most_used_skill": {
        "doc_count": 5,
        "skill": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Skill 1",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Skill 2",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Skill 3",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Skill 4",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "Skill 5",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if i want to return the id of the skill object as well alongwith the keyword, how can i do that? Is there even a way to return additional information along with the aggregation?

Comment: Imagine `"keyword": "Skill 1"` is used in 2000 documents. Do you want the aggregation to give you 2000 IDs? I guess it would be better to first aggregate (like you did) and then query for docs matching `"keyword": "Skill 1"`. Fells like a more direct approach with less overhead, because the aggregation call would become very expensive if it did what you wanted.

Comment: No i dont want that. Yes you are right that would be extremely expensive. Thank you for the insight. I will go with the solution that you have suggested.